# as.Date() not giving desired result. (giving NA)

Tags: r, as.date

I read a .xlsx file containing Date columns into R and converted it into dataframe.
Some date columns are being read correctly but most of the others are getting converted to "43116" format.
Any attempt to convert it into Date using as.Date(, origin= <>, format=<>) is returning NA.
I have tried all possible solutions like using 'stringAsFactors = FALSE', POSIT thing and checking the excel file for date formats but nothing worked.
Please help.

Comment: is it being read in as a character or number

Comment: @Mike All the source columns are of Date format. But some of those getting read are of character type.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: @Ryan In R, try to assign "43129" to a variable. How will you convert this to Date format without getting NA?

Comment: @Mike I have found the fix. I tried to deal with a shorter datafile and it gave correct results. However, while dealing with the entire dataset, erroneous results occurred due to unclean data. Even if one entry in the column varied from the normal Date format, the entire column was getting converted into 'character' type instead of Date format. Though, could you still try to find a fix for the query I posted for Ryan on this thread?

Comment: `as.Date(as.numeric(df$var), origin = '1970-01-01')` Should work where `df` is your dataframe and `var` is the variable of interest.

Comment: Assuming Excel on Windows try `as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(as.numeric("43116"))` .  See page 30 of https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf for details.

Comment: In excel change the column format to a custom format, and do mm-dd-YYYY or whatever format you have, then read it in as a POSIXct object with the same format. If saving the excel as a csv save the column changes and then exit, it will prompt you again to save it, press no.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to recreate the problem if no data is provided, but if you want to convert the number 43129 or the character "43129" to a R date you should do the following:

```
a <- 43129
b <- '43129'

format(as.Date(a, origin = "1899-12-30"), '%Y-%m-%d')
[1] "2018-01-29"

format(as.Date(as.integer(b), origin = "1899-12-30"), '%Y-%m-%d')
[1] "2018-01-29"
```

I used the format yyyy-mm-dd, but any other date format could be used if you format it properly.
Hope it helps!